# $p$-adic exponential function

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Simple question about $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. How do I evaluate $$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ where $x\in {\mathbb Q}_p$. I'm a bit confused, because as far as I understand it, each term is added in the same way as in $\mathbb R$, so why should the result be different?
As a start let's evaluate $x=1$ in $p=3$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that series doesn't even converge at $x=1$, so we are already in trouble...

Comment: Ok, I see $|x|_p < p^{1/(1-p)}$, so I guess $x=2$ should be fine.

Comment: $|2|_3 = 1$, no?  Also, more generally, you ask "why should the result [of $p$-adic exponentiation] be different [from real exponentiation]?"  Real numbers and $p$-adic numbers are not the same kinds of objects.  The exponential of a $p$-adic number is not, in general, a rational number, and therefore not a real number.  Moreover, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "evaluating" that series.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: For $p=3$, $p^{1/(1-p)} = 3^{-1/2}$, so neither $x=2$ nor $x=1$ are fine.  $x=3$ would be allowed.

Comment: `The exponential of a p-adic number is not, in general, a rational number, and therefore not a real number.` Not a real number???
Ok let me elaborate: Since $x=3$ has absolute value $1/3$, the series should converge. So I'm looking for some $y \in {\mathbb Q}_p$, such that for $\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists N \in {\mathbb N} \quad \forall n\geq N : \left|y-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|_p < \epsilon$

Comment: Diger, I removed a sentence from your post. Having it there won't help your cause, and only closed a window of opportunity to get the question promptly reopened. The first edit puts an "on hold"-question into a queue for reopening. Your edit gave it a snowball's chance in hell to actually get reopened = a lost opportunity.

Comment: Anyway, your confusion seems to originate from a misunderstanding of the relation of the $p$-adics and the reals. Basically what happens is that $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$_p intersect **reliably** only in $\Bbb{Q}$. Converging sequences or series take you outside the rationals, but there is no way to compare the limits should they exist in both domains. Listing a few examples you are likely to have seen. A) The geometric series
$$
1+2+4+8+16+\cdots
$$ diverges in $\Bbb{R}$ but converges to $-1$ in $\Bbb{Q}_2$. The sum formula of a geometric series, $a/(1-q)$, holds whenever $q$ is "small".

Comment: (cont'd) B) Because $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $7$ the equation $x^2=2$ has two solutions in $\Bbb{Q}_7$. However, it is unwise to try and identify either with real numbers $\pm\sqrt2$. This is because in $\Bbb{Q}_7$ we don't have useful notions of positive and negative. Mind you, we can still call those solutions $\pm\sqrt2$, but to distinguish them we need to specify them differently. One way would be to say that $\sqrt2$ is the solution of $x^2=2$ such that $x\equiv3\pmod 7$ (the other solution is congruent to $-3\equiv4$). This is a bit arbitrary and not usually done.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but I don't quite see it: What does $\mod 7$ have to do with $x^2=2$ having 2 solutions in ${\mathbb Q}_7$. From Wikipedia: `More formally, the p-adic expansions can be used to define the field Qp of p-adic numbers while the p-adic integers form a subring of Qp, denoted Zp. (Not to be confused with the ring of integers modulo p which is also sometimes written Zp...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to try $\exp(3)$ in $p=3$, here are the first few partial sums:
$$ \eqalign{1 &= 1\cr
            1 + 3 &= 1 + 3\cr
            1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} &= 1+3+2 \cdot 3^2+ 3^3+3^4+\ldots\cr
            1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{2} &= 1 + 3 + 3^2\cr
            1+ 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{2} + \dfrac{27}{8} &= 1 + 3 + 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^3 + 2 \cdot 3^4 + \ldots\cr
            1 +3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{2} + \dfrac{27}{8} + \dfrac{81}{40} &=
    1 + 3 + 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^3  + 0 \cdot 3^4 + \ldots\cr
  1 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{2} + \dfrac{27}{8} + \dfrac{81}{40} + \frac{81}{80} &= 1 + 3 + 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^3  + 2 \cdot 3^4 + \ldots\cr}$$
and it turns out all later terms have numerators with higher powers of $3$ than $3^4$, so the start of the $3$-adic expansion of $\exp(3)$ is 
$ 1 + 3 + 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^3  + 2 \cdot 3^4 + \ldots$.  As was mentioned, this is a $3$-adic number, not the same as the real number $\exp(3)$, nor any other real number.

Comment: So the final value is in ${\mathbb Q}_p$ or only in ${\mathbb C}_p$ ? The expansion looks as if it is a normal $p$-adic number in ${\mathbb Q}_p$. But can I not assign a numeric value to a $p$-adic number?

Comment: It is in $\mathbb Q_3$, as it is the sum of a convergent series in $\mathbb Q_3$.  No, you should not assign a value in $\mathbb R$ to a $p$-adic number.

Comment: This particular series converges in $\mathbb R$ to a certain member of $\mathbb R$, and in $\mathbb Q_3$ to a certain member of $\mathbb Q_3$.  But it would be a mistake to identify the member of $\mathbb Q_3$ with the member of $\mathbb R$, because there are other series that converge in $\mathbb Q_3$ to the same member of $\mathbb Q_3$ but converge in $\mathbb R$ to a different member of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Couple of Questions:
1. What do you mean by ...converge to a different member in $\mathbb R$ ? Do you have an example?
2. How do you derive the expansion of a rational number $p/q$ ?
3. The specific number $9/2$ is equal to $2\cdot 3^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, 3^n$ ? 4. What is the major advantage to stay in this system of numbers if it is basically just reexpressing stuff from another system?

Comment: @Diger: $\frac{n!}{n! + 1}$ is an example of a sequence of rational numbers that converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, but converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. You shouldn't expect there to be any relationship between limits in $\mathbb{R}$ and limits in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ unless you have a very good reason. If you insist on an example using sums, take $\frac{0!}{0! + 1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)! + 1} - \frac{n!}{n! + 1} \right) $

Comment: But the latter sum is zero in $\mathbb R$ and ${\mathbb Q}_p$, or?

Comment: The $n$'th partial sum is $n!/(n!+1)$.  As stated, this converges in $\mathbb R$ to $1$ and in $\mathbb Q_p$ to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The reals (and complexes) are *truly different* from the various $p$-adic fields $\Bbb Q_p$. One of the glaring differences is the domain of convergence of exponential and logarithm.

For $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$, the exponential series is convergent for no matter what $z$ you plug into it, while the logarithmic series is convergent only for $|z|<1$.

For any $p$-adic field (including the complete extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$), the logarithmic series is still convergent for $z$ with $|z|<1$, but for convergence of the exponential series, you need the very restrictive condition $|z|<\varepsilon^{\frac1{p-1}}$, where $\varepsilon=|p|$ must be a positive real number $<1$, and $\varepsilon=1/p$ is the conventional choice. The above restriction means that you can calculate the $3$-adic value of $\exp(3)$, as @RobertIsrael has done in his answer, but you can not calculate the $2$-adic exponential of $2$.

Now that I’m on my hobby-horse, I must ride it a bit further. The real logarithm extends from its domain of convergence to a homomorphism from the group $\Bbb R^{>0}$ onto $\Bbb R$, multiplicative group to additive group. The complex logarithm has no such extension: there is no group containing $1+\{z\in\Bbb C:\,|z|<1\}$ on which the logarithm can be defined as a homomorphism.

The $p$-adic logarithm is much more wonderful (and useful) than the complex, for if $k$ is a complete $p$-adic field, the set $1+\{z\in k:\,|z|<1\}$ is a multiplicative group, and the logarithmic series defines a homomorphism from it to the additive group $k$. If you have a $p$-adic number $z$, you could try to define $\exp(z)$ as a number $\zeta$ such that $\log(\zeta)=z$, and this equation is always solvable, for $\zeta$ perhaps in a finite field extension of $\Bbb Q_p$. Only problem is that there are infinitely many such $\zeta$, and in most cases, there is little reason to choose one of these over the others. In my opinion, this is the deep reason why you can’t define the exponential of most $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by `there is not such homomorphism for the complex logarithm.`. Isn't the logarithm on the right half plane $\left\{z \in {\mathbb C} : {\rm Re}(z) >0\right\}$ such a homomorphism as $\log(xy)=\log x + \log y$, or must it hold for any number of arguments i.e. $\log(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \log x_1 + ... + \log x_n$ ??? This is truly not the case.

Comment: @Diger, the right half plane is not a group, and a homomorphism needs a group as its domain.